# Dropdowns to Collapse when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie in coding and I wonder if it's possible to create multiple dropdown menus, and whenever you click outside an opened box, I want it to be collapsed. I am sharing the code I wrote but it's not working since one dropdown is collapsing when clicking outside, but the other one isn't. Can you help me with that? I'm sharing the code and I want 3 dropdown menus. I'm struggling with this for weeks now and I haven't succeeded yet. Thanks in advance!

```
    HTML Code

    <div class="container">
      <a href="#home"><span class="Agencymenu">Home</span></a>
      <a href="#news"><span class="Agencymenu">News</span></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Team 1</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 1</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 2</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 3</span></a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown2">
        <button class="dropbtn2" onclick="myFunction2()">Team 2</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content2" id="myDropdown2">
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 1</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 2</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="Agencymenu">Link 3</span></a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>

CSS Code

        .Agencymenu {
        font-family: 'AGENCYB' !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 24pt;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #30333c;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .container a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;    
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family:AGENCYB;
        font-size:30px;
    }

    .container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #0C0;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #30333c;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .show {
        display: block;
    }

    .container2 {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #30333c;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .container2 a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown2 {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown2 .dropbtn2 {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;    
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family:AGENCYB;
        font-size:30px;
    }

    .container2 a:hover, .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
        background-color: #0C0;
    }

    .dropdown-content2 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #30333c;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content2 a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content2 a:hover {
        background-color: #0C0;
    }

    .show2 {
        display: block;
    }

JS Code:  

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show2");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show2')) {
        myDropdown.classList.remove('show2');
      }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show2");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
    var myDropdown2 = document.getElementById("myDropdown2");
      if (myDropdown2.classList.contains('show2')) {
        myDropdown2.classList.remove('show2');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you really need javascript to do this? CSS only solution will work for you? and do you really need it on click or it works if done on hover?

Comment: I don't understand why did you chose another answer over mine?

Comment: I am a newbie in the website and I don't know how it works actually. I don't mean to offend you but your suggestion was the best one. The other one was also helpful so I gave it an OK but I didn't know that I can only give one OK to a question, so I am correcting it. Please don't be offended. Thanks for your helpful and understanding comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are okay using CSS only solution and you need dropdown on hover, you can simply use this code

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block}
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hkred6d7/1/

if you need it on click, let me know here in comment. it will require JS

Comment: How does hover work in smartphones in your code?? I'm shocked. I think this is fine, but whenever I click outside the box, I want the menu to be collapsed. I think in your version, when you click a menu, the other one collapses. I want the menu to be collapsed if clicking outside of it. Thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: I am really sorry though, I want the menu to be collapsed when clicked on it again. So the system works like this: You click the menu, it opens, if you click on it again, or click anywhere on the page, it collapses.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hkred6d7/7/ here is small JS to make it work on click event. but i recommend using the hover method because when you use actual link later, when you click on the link it goes to another page anyway. and about your question of how it's working on smartphones, hover works on tap for smartphones.

Comment: You're the man! Thank you. Quick question: if I change the bg-color of hover, would it corrupt the code? I want the menus' background to turn green when the mouse is (hover) on it. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can do it

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier with jQuery, but here is an example with vanilla JS. The key here is to reuse a css class for all dropdowns

https://jsfiddle.net/fyjjzhqw/

```
//HTML
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="Dropdown">
    <div class="Dropdown__btn">Dropdown 1</div>
     <ul class="Dropdown__list">
       <li>Item A</li>
       <li>Item B</li>
       <li>Item C</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="Dropdown">
    <div class="Dropdown__btn">Dropdown 2</div>
     <ul class="Dropdown__list">
       <li>Item A</li>
       <li>Item B</li>
       <li>Item C</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="Dropdown">
    <div class="Dropdown__btn">Dropdown 3</div>
     <ul class="Dropdown__list">
       <li>Item A</li>
       <li>Item B</li>
       <li>Item C</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>

// CSS
.Dropdown__list {
 display: none
}

.is-opened.Dropdown .Dropdown__list {
 display: block
}

//JS

var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.Dropdown');


var closeAll = function() {
 dropdowns.forEach( function(current) {
     current.classList.remove('is-opened')
 })
}
var toggleDropdown = function(e) {
 closeAll();
 var dropdown = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
 dropdown.classList.toggle('is-opened')
}
for (i = dropdowns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 dropdowns[i].querySelector('.Dropdown__btn').addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this https://jsfiddle.net/aswin_89/hkred6d7/9/

modified your JS a bit

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
   event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show2");
}

function clearClasses (target){
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show2').forEach((item)=>{
    if(event.target.nextElementSibling !== item)
      item.classList.remove('show2');
  })
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  clearClasses(event.target.nextElementSibling);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that your JS is not working properly. I click on the dropdowns but nothing happens. Can you check it out again?

Comment: Sorry i forget to wrap the javascript inside head portion.. check the [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aswin_89/hkred6d7/9/)